# How to add a new matter for physics in blender ? (aluminium, titanium etc.)

Tags: add-on

I couldnt find a way to add matters to blender. I need it for calculating object mass. When i do calculate the mass, blender appears me some options to set the matter (iron, brass etc.) and of course there is a "**custom**" option. How can add my "**custom**" matter to that list? I dont want to choose **custom** every single time i do calculate...
[image]

As you can see, there is a matter list that comes with blender. I wanna add my custom matters to that list. So i'll be able to select my own matter quickly...

Comment: I would expect this list accessible from blender presets folder, but there is not any for mass ... so sadly it seems to be hardcoded. Also any time you change object size you would have to calculate mass again (it is not updated automatically). So ... it seems to be a task for someone with python skills :)

Answer (score 8):

**Extra menu script.**

AFAIK there is no simple way to tack extra material / density pairs to the operator enum. It is however quite simple, via scripting,  to add a menu of extra options.

[image]

The value is the density in kg/m³

> **[Chalk](https://www.aqua-calc.com/page/density-table/substance/chalk-coma-and-blank-solid)**, solid weighs 2.499 gram per cubic centimeter or 2 499 kilogram
> per cubic meter, i.e. density of chalk, solid is equal to 2 499 kg/m³

In default SI units, the default blender cube has volume 8 m³ multiplying volume by density will give mass, for chalk (*as illustrated*) 19992 kg.

[Densities of various materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density#Various_materials)

Quick slap together proof of concept using *`Templates > Python > UI Menu Simple`*  Material "Foo" has density 12.0, "Bar" 0.01,  etc.

```
import bpy

extra_mats = (
    ("Foo", 12.0),
    ("Bar", 0.01),
    ("Goo", 11),
    )
class SimpleCustomMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Extras"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_simple_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        for name, p in extra_mats:
            op = layout.operator(
                "rigidbody.mass_calculate", 
                text=f"{name} ({p})"
                )
            op.density = p
            op.material = "Custom"
        

def draw_menu(self, context):
    row = self.layout.row()
    row.operator("rigidbody.mass_calculate")
    row.menu(SimpleCustomMenu.bl_idname)
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleCustomMenu)
    bpy.types.PHYSICS_PT_rigid_body_settings.prepend(draw_menu)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleCustomMenu)
    bpy.types.PHYSICS_PT_rigid_body_settings.remove(draw_menu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # The menu can also be called from scripts
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=SimpleCustomMenu.bl_idname)
```